# Valid Objective-C method is invalid in Objective-C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I've just changed an `ObjC` file to `ObjC++` by changing the extension from `.m` to `.mm`. Now, one of my methods gives the error: **Expected expression**

The following code is an example that works fine in `ObjC` but NOT in `ObjC++`:

```
- (float)sum:(float)a and:(float)b
{
    return a+b;
}

- (void)run
{
    float s = [self sum:1.5f and:2.5f]; // ERROR HERE
    NSLog(@"Sum = %.1f", s);
}
```

The only thing I've changed is the file extension. Any idea what's going on and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Is "and" a reserved word in C++?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/as400clr33.htm#HDRALT_REPR_OPS_PUNCTS (Scan for "alternative" if the link doesn't take you there.)

Comment: An embarrassing mistake... thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: For a 'better' version of what @HotLicks is saying, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), it's at the top of this list.

Comment: I'd suggest a naming change;   `sumFloat:float:` or `sumCount:ofFloats:`.   I.e. your API should describe both what it does and what it does it with.  This both makes the API more descriptive and it eliminates type collisions.  And it'd happen to fix this problem.

Comment: Please make the correct answer an answer so it can be flagged as such and accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`and` is a reserved word in C/C++...

(See comments under question)